# How to use a custom auth claim to query firestore (with vuexfire)

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuex

In my vuex I have one custom auth claim saved to state as claims(state.claims). I can read this from the state in my vue components just fine and I can also see it in vue devtools.

But when I try to use state.claims to query a firestore collection,
 ***Sometimes*** I get null(the default value in the state), or an error that I could not replicate saying that is was a "custom object B"

It works the first time loaded but after one refresh it breaks until I switch views back and forth

My guess is that it isn't grabbing the value fast enough for claims but I am not sure

**Vuex store**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import { vuexfireMutations, firestoreAction } from 'vuexfire'
import {db} from "@/components/fbInit.js";
import firebase from 'firebase'

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({

  state: {    
    tests:  [],
    claims: [],
    user:       null,
    isLoggedIn: false,

  },

  mutations: {
    ...vuexfireMutations,

    setUser: state => {
      if (firebase.auth().currentUser) {
        state.isLoggedIn = true;
        state.user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        state.claims = firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdTokenResult().then((idTokenResult) => {
          state.claims = idTokenResult.claims.company
        }) .catch((error) => {
          // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
          console.log(error);
        });
      }
    },

  },

  actions: {

    //  GET documents in a collection/subcollection and put them into state
    getFire:  firestoreAction(({ bindFirestoreRef, state }) => {
      //return the promise returned by 'bindFirestoreRef'
      return bindFirestoreRef('tests', db.collection(state.claims))
    }), 

 setUser: context => {
      context.commit('setUser');  //context.commit to perform mutation
    },
  }
})
```

**Vue Component**

```
<template>
  <div class="pa-9">
    <div>
      <v-card light>
        {{ this.claims}} 
      </v-card>
       <v-card >
        {{ this.tests }}
      </v-card>
    </div>
  </div>

</template>

<script>

import {db, functions } from '../components/fbInit'
import { mapState }   from 'vuex'
import { mapActions } from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: "Claims",

  data: () => ({

  }),
  created() {
    this.setUser()
    this.getFire()

      },

    computed: {
    ...mapState ([
      'events','wow','user','isLoggedIn', 'claims','tests'
    ]),
  },

  methods: {

     ...mapActions([ 'setUser', 'getFire',  ]),

      });
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

**ERRORS**

```
FirebaseError: Function Firestore.collection() requires its first argument to be of type non-empty string, but it was: a custom B object

[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'B'
    |     property 'c' -> object with constructor 'B'
    |     property 'b' -> object with constructor 'Wb'
    --- property 'a' closes the circle"
FirebaseError: Function Firestore.collection() requires its first argument to be of type non-empty string, but it was: null
```

**EDIT Main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'

require('dotenv').config();
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify';
// require('@/components/fb.js')
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import './components/fbInit'

import * as VueGoogleMaps from 'vue2-google-maps';



Vue.config.productionTip = false
/* eslint-disable */
let app;
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if(!app) {
    app = new Vue({
      router,
      vuetify,store,
      render: h => h(App)
    }).$mount('#app')
  }
})
```

Comment: Can you please add your `main.js` file to your question?

Comment: I have added my main.js. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found some [doc](https://vuefire.vuejs.org/api/vuexfire.html#vuexfiremutations) . Looking at example there `state` in `firestoreAction(({ bindFirestoreRef, state })` should be after `}`. So it should be:

`firestoreAction(({ bindFirestoreRef }, state )`

however I am not sure if it will work without `unbindFirestoreRef`...

I hope it will help you!

Comment: I have several other actions that work with that syntax.I just excluded them. Thank you though